# How do I create a Vue bus for global event handling?

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, vue-router, event-bus

I'm using Vue on a Node/Webpack/Vue Router environment and trying to setup a global event handler or bus. But it's not working. It's showing up as undefined. Here's my setup:

**main.js:**

```
//Declare event handler
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$bus', {
  get () {
    return this.$root.bus
  }
})

//Declare app instance
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
  created: () => {
    console.log(this.$bus);
  }
}
</script>
```

The `console.log` statement returns `undefined`, meaning the event handler somehow isn't getting passed to the app. I've also tried the following statement to declare the event handler:

**main.js**

```
//Declare event handler
const eventBus = new Vue()
Vue.prototype.$bus = eventBus
```

But that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with using the arrow function. While the `() => {}` syntax looks nicer than `function() {}`, there is a difference, in that the the arrow function uses a lexical context for `this` (from where it was defined, instead of from where it was called, which id what you need in this instance), meaning that `this` is no longer the Vue instance, so you cannot use `this.$bus`. You can fix this by replacing the arrow function with a regular function using either `created: function() {...` or the concise (but functionally equivalent) version `created() {...`

You can read up more on the differences by looking up articles on `es6, arrow functions, lexical scope, this context`.

main.js code:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";

Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

somewhere in app.js

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  created() {
    console.log(this.$bus);
  }
};
```

Comment: D'oh! Sure enough, that was the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "_the arrow function creates it's own `this` context_" I am sure you do not mean to phrase it that way. It shares the same `this` context as where it is _declared_. Whereas `function` gets the `this` from where it is _called_.

Comment: yes, thank you for pointing that out. I  Also the quote from MSDN was misleading. I find that this explanation alone doesn't not make it clear *why* the declared context wouldn't work.